# Why the index is showing [object Object] and not an integer in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, loops, next.js

it's been a while since I've used React, but I'm having an issue.

When I console.log my index inside the map function, my console shows me:

[image]

But then the result in my browser shows:

[object Object]1
[image]

I would expect this to show the index + 1, so the first would be 1, second 2, the third 3 and so on. Here's my code:

```
import React from "react";
import Container from '../Container'
import content from '../../content/landing'

function Step(index: any) {
    return (
        <div className="rounded-full h-12 w-12 bg-yellow border-4 border-black">
            {index + 1}
        </div>
    )
}

function HowItWorks() {

    const listItems = content?.howto?.map((c:any, index:any) => {
        console.log(index, 'index')
        return (
            <div className="mb-12 filter-none shadow-1 bg-white p-4 py-8 rounded-lg border-4 border-black" key={index}>
                <Step index={index}/>
                <h3 className="text-xl font-bold">{c.title}</h3>
                <p className="text-xl">{c.text}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }

    );
    return (
      <div className="bg-purple-600 py-12">
        <Container>
            <h2 className="text-4xl text-white font-bold">How it works</h2>
            {listItems}
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  export default HowItWorks;
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're using typescript, define index as number instead of any and see what your results are

Comment: The component takes props, not index. You may change it to "props.index" or use the argument destructurization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not destructuring `index` in your Step component, so "index" is your entire props object:

```js
function Step(index: any) {
```

Should be:

```js
function Step({index: any}) {
```